# Matlab: Filled contour plot with imcontour

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, contour, contourf

I am trying to create a filled contour plot from an image in MATLAB. However, the command `imcontour` does not seem to have an option for filled contours. If I use `contourf`, it draws all the contour lines in black. Since the image has a lot of contour levels, it is shown almost completely in black.

Does anybody know how to make a filled `imcontour` or how to meaningfully apply `contourf` on an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no filled version of `imcontour` because in theory, the image itself *is* the filled version.

```
data = load('clown');
img = ind2rgb(data.X, data.map);

imshow(img);
hold on
imcontour(img(:,:,1), 3);
```

[image]

You could use `contourf` though, and [specify the line color](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fcontour.html?#input_argument_namevalue_linecolor). By specifying a value of `'none'` no lines  will be shown.

```
c = contourf(data, 2, 'LineColor', 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: This picture is creepy.

Comment: @plasmacel [Fear of clowns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulrophobia) is common in a lot of people.

Comment: How did you get a picture of my nightmares?